# Writing to a specific hazelcast node

Tags: hazelcast

I've got three web services that each own a Hazelcast node, which are connected in a 3 ring cluster. When I send a request to a web server, I would like to write to the hazelcast instance that the server owns, not whatever the primary key partitions into. How can I do this?

Comment: you want to write in a Map/Queue that is shared by all 3 Hazelcast instances?

Comment: Could you please add more details to the question ? Which data structure are you talking about ? What do you intend to achieve by this approach ?